# how to order my cloud firestore data that I got in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a chat app using flutter, dart and firebase and everything is working fine except that when I type a message in my chat app it's not ordered correctly sometimes it get's created on the top and sometimes in the bottom and other times in the middle and I don't know what to do this is the code for the chat page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flash_chat/constants.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

// ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
var loggedInUser;

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatScreen({super.key});
  static String id = '/chat_screen';
  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final messageTextController = TextEditingController();
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String? messageText;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }
  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try{
      final user = _auth.currentUser;
      if(user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
      }
    } catch(e) {
      //ignore: avoid_print
      print(e);
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: null,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
                _auth.signOut();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }),
        ],
        title: const Text('⚡️Chat'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            const MessagesStream(),
            Container(
              decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: messageTextController,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        messageText = value;
                      },
                      decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      messageTextController.clear();
                      _firestore.collection('messages').add({
                        'text': messageText,
                        'sender': loggedInUser.email,
                      });
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      'Send',
                      style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MessagesStream extends StatelessWidget {
  const MessagesStream({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map>>(
      stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(!snapshot.hasData) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,),
          );
        }
        final messages = snapshot.data?.docs.reversed;
        List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
        for (var message in messages!) {
          final messageText = message.data()['text'];
          final messageSender = message.data()['sender'];
          final currentUser = loggedInUser.email;
          final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
            text: messageText,
            sender: messageSender,
            isMe: currentUser == messageSender,
          );
          messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
        }
        return Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            reverse: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 10),
            children: messageBubbles,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  const MessageBubble({super.key, this.sender, this.text, this.isMe});
  final String? sender;
  final String? text;
  final bool? isMe;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: isMe! ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            sender!,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12,
              color: Colors.black54,
            ),
          ),
          Material(
            elevation: 5,
            borderRadius: isMe! ? const BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
            ) : const BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(30),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
            ),
            color: isMe! ? Colors.lightBlueAccent : Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
              child: Text(
                '$text',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15,
                  color: isMe! ? Colors.white : Colors.black54,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried using the orderBy, but it didn't work.

Comment: "it didn't work" is hard to help with. Edit your question to show what you tried with `orderBy`, and what output you got.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.